# How can I read matrix array different way in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have a 8x8 matrix array. I want to read matrix values (elements) as shown in the picture.
Ho can I do it?

I've defined array like this.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[][] myArray = new int[8][8];

    int start = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<8; j++) {
            myArray[i][j] = start;
            start++;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Image is here]

Comment: What have you tried so far? And why are you reading in the data in this order?

Comment: Are you seeking a solution for a matrix with any dimensions? Does it have to be a square matrix? (i.e. number of rows equals number of columns)

Comment: I need this for a project. The number of rows and columns is not always equal.

Comment: We are not a homework-writing service.

Comment: its not homework bro 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you solve any coding problem?  One step at a time.

Following the path in your picture, let's list the first several integer array subscripts.

```
0, 7
0, 6
1, 7
2, 7
1, 6
0, 5
0, 4
1, 5
2, 6
3, 7
```

You need to list enough subscripts to see the pattern that develops.

One possible solution would be to code the subscripts in a different array.  Unfortunately, this solution would lock you into an 8 x 8 matrix.

So, let's write some code to get the first few values of the matrix.  It's not going to be pretty code.  We're still trying to figure out the pattern.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayWalk {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int height = 8;
        int width = 8;

        ArrayWalk aw = new ArrayWalk();
        int[][] myArray = aw.createArray(height, width);
        int[] values = aw.walkArray(myArray);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
    }

    private int[][] createArray(int height, int width) {
        int[][] myArray = new int[height][width];

        int start = 0;

        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
            for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
                myArray[h][w] = start;
                start++;
            }
        }

        return myArray;
    }

    private int[] walkArray(int[][] myArray) {
        int height = myArray.length;
        int width = myArray[0].length;
        int length = height * width;
        int[] values = new int[length];
        int index = 0;

        int h = 0;
        int w = width - 1;
        values[index++] = myArray[h][w];

        w--;
        values[index++] = myArray[h][w];

        h++;
        w++;
        values[index++] = myArray[h][w];

        h++;
        values[index++] = myArray[h][w];

        h--;
        w--;
        values[index++] = myArray[h][w];

        h--;
        w--;
        values[index++] = myArray[h][w];

        w--;
        values[index++] = myArray[h][w];

        h++;
        w++;
        values[index++] = myArray[h][w];

        h++;
        w++;
        values[index++] = myArray[h][w];

        h++;
        w++;
        values[index++] = myArray[h][w];

        h++;
        values[index++] = myArray[h][w];

        h--;
        w--;
        values[index++] = myArray[h][w];

        h--;
        w--;
        values[index++] = myArray[h][w];

        h--;
        w--;
        values[index++] = myArray[h][w];

        h--;
        w--;
        values[index++] = myArray[h][w];

        return values;
    }

}
```

As you can see, we've determined that we need to set the width and height of the matrix, and we need to return an integer array to hold the matrix values.

So far, so good.

More importantly, we see a pattern developing.  Let's just look at the subscripts.

```
w--

h++
w++   (once)

h++

h--
w--   (twice)
```

This pattern repeats, with the exception that the double subscript repeats once, twice, three times, up to seven times (the width - one).  Then the double subscript repeats six, five, four, etc. times.

The top row and bottom row always shift to the left.  The first column and last column always shift down.

Now, at this point, I'm not sure if what I just said works for a rectangular matrix.  I'm pretty sure that it works for a square matrix.

Let's code a helper method with the knowledge we've gained.  This pattern is a factory pattern.

```
private Dimension[] createIncrements() {
    Dimension[] increments = new Dimension[4];
    increments[0] = new Dimension(-1, 0);
    increments[1] = new Dimension(1, 1);
    increments[2] = new Dimension(0, 1);
    increments[3] = new Dimension(-1, -1);
    return increments;
}
```

A java.awt.Dimension holds a width and a height.  So, we define the four increments that we saw in the code pattern.  We can then cycle through these increments.  The trick will be keeping track of how many times we need to increment using the first and third (zero-based) increment.  We'll have to count up from 1 to 7 and back down to 1.

I've been experimenting for several hours now.  This is a hard problem to solve.  I'll pick up where I left off tomorrow.

I hope the description that I've given you so far is helpful.

Edited to add: I'm not sure I'd have come up with the algorithm in the other answers.  All I did ultimately was to write some code to test different array sizes.

Here are the results of one test.

```
-------------------
|   0 |   1 |   2 |
-------------------
|   3 |   4 |   5 |
-------------------
|   6 |   7 |   8 |
-------------------

[2, 1, 5, 8, 4, 0, 3, 7, 6]
```

Another test

```
-------------------------------
|   0 |   1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |
-------------------------------
|   5 |   6 |   7 |   8 |   9 |
-------------------------------

[4, 3, 9, 8, 2, 1, 7, 6, 0, 5]
```

Finally, the 8 x 8 test from the image.

```
-------------------------------------------------
|   0 |   1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |   5 |   6 |   7 |
-------------------------------------------------
|   8 |   9 |  10 |  11 |  12 |  13 |  14 |  15 |
-------------------------------------------------
|  16 |  17 |  18 |  19 |  20 |  21 |  22 |  23 |
-------------------------------------------------
|  24 |  25 |  26 |  27 |  28 |  29 |  30 |  31 |
-------------------------------------------------
|  32 |  33 |  34 |  35 |  36 |  37 |  38 |  39 |
-------------------------------------------------
|  40 |  41 |  42 |  43 |  44 |  45 |  46 |  47 |
-------------------------------------------------
|  48 |  49 |  50 |  51 |  52 |  53 |  54 |  55 |
-------------------------------------------------
|  56 |  57 |  58 |  59 |  60 |  61 |  62 |  63 |
-------------------------------------------------

[7, 6, 15, 23, 14, 5, 4, 13, 22, 31, 39, 30, 21, 12, 3, 2, 11, 20, 29, 38, 
47, 55, 46, 37, 28, 19, 10, 1, 0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 62, 53, 44, 35, 
26, 17, 8, 16, 25, 34, 43, 52, 61, 60, 51, 42, 33, 24, 32, 41, 50, 59, 58, 
49, 40, 48, 57, 56]
```

And here's the code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayWalk {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int height = 8;
        int width = 8;

        ArrayWalk aw = new ArrayWalk();
        int[][] myArray = aw.createArray(height, width);
        System.out.println(aw.printArray(myArray));

        int[] values = aw.walkArray(myArray);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
    }

    private int[][] createArray(int height, int width) {
        int[][] myArray = new int[height][width];

        int start = 0;

        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
            for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
                myArray[h][w] = start;
                start++;
            }
        }

        return myArray;
    }

    private int[] walkArray(int[][] myArray) {
        int totalRows = myArray.length;
        int totalCols = myArray[0].length;

        List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>(totalRows * totalCols);
        List<Integer> diagonal = new ArrayList<>(
                Math.max(totalRows, totalCols));

        boolean reverseOrder = true;

        for (int col = totalCols - 1; col >= 0; col--) {
            for (int row = 0; row < totalRows && col + row < totalCols; row++) {
                diagonal.add(myArray[row][col + row]);
            }

            if (reverseOrder) {
                Collections.reverse(diagonal);
            }

            res.addAll(diagonal);
            reverseOrder = !reverseOrder;
            diagonal.clear();
        }

        for (int row = 1; row < totalRows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < totalCols && col + row < totalRows; col++) {
                diagonal.add(myArray[col + row][col]);
            }

            if (reverseOrder) {
                Collections.reverse(diagonal);
            }

            res.addAll(diagonal);
            reverseOrder = !reverseOrder;
            diagonal.clear();
        }

        int[] output = new int[res.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++) {
            output[i] = res.get(i);
        }
        return output;
    }

    private String printArray(int[][] myArray) {
        String output = "";
        for (int h = 0; h < myArray.length; h++) {
            output += printDashes(myArray[h].length) + "\n";
            output += printLine(myArray[h]) + "\n";
        }
        output += printDashes(myArray[0].length) + "\n";
        return output;
    }

    private String printDashes(int width) {
        int count = width * 6 + 1;
        String output = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            output += "-";
        }

        return output;
    }

    private String printLine(int[] array) {
        String output = "|";

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            String value = String.format("%3d", array[i]);
            output += " " + value + " |";
        }

        return output;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks brother. Working superb 

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<Integer> readMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
    int totalRows = matrix.length;
    int totalCols = matrix[0].length;

    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>(totalRows * totalCols);
    List<Integer> diagonal = new ArrayList<>(Math.max(totalRows, totalCols));

    boolean reverseOrder = true;

    for (int col = totalCols - 1; col >= 0; col--) {
        for (int row = 0; row < totalRows && col + row < totalCols; row++)
            diagonal.add(matrix[row][col + row]);

        if (reverseOrder)
            Collections.reverse(diagonal);

        res.addAll(diagonal);
        reverseOrder = !reverseOrder;
        diagonal.clear();
    }

    for (int row = 1; row < totalRows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < totalCols && col + row < totalRows; col++)
            diagonal.add(matrix[col + row][col]);

        if (reverseOrder)
            Collections.reverse(diagonal);

        res.addAll(diagonal);
        reverseOrder = !reverseOrder;
        diagonal.clear();
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. Code contains comments explaining the traversal algorithm.

```java
public class MatrixTraversal {
    private static int[][]  matrix;

    private static void displayElement(int row, int col, int length, int count) {
        System.out.printf("%" + length + "d. Next  element [%" + length + "d][%" + length + "d] = %" + length + "d%n",
                          (count + 1),
                          row,
                          col,
                          matrix[row][col]);
    }

    private static void displayMatrix() {
        int length = getLength();
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                if (j > 0  &&  j < matrix[i].length) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.printf("%" + length + "d", matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static int getLength() {
        int rows = matrix.length;
        int cols = matrix[0].length;
        int number = rows * cols;
        int length = (int) (Math.log10(number) + 1);
        return length;
    }

    private static void initMatrix(int rows, int cols) {
        System.out.printf("rows = %d , columns = %d%n", rows, cols);
        System.out.println();
        if (rows > 0  &&  cols > 0) {
            matrix = new int[rows][cols];
            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                    matrix[row][col] = (row * cols) + col;
                }
            }
            displayMatrix();
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("rows and columns must both be positive");
        }
    }

    // Algorithm:
    // 1. Start at first row, last column.
    // 2. Go to same row, column to left.
    //    a. If can't go left, go down one row, i.e. same column, next row.
    //    b. If can't go left, go to step 3.
    // 3. Go diagonally down and to the right until reach either last row or last column.
    //    a. If can't go diagonally down and to the right, go to 4.
    // 4. Go to same column, next row.
    //    a. If can't go down, go left, i.e. same row, column to left.
    //    b. If can't go left, go to step 5.
    // 5. Go diagonally up and to the left until reach either first row or first column.
    //    a. If can't go diagonally up and to the left, go to 6.
    // 6. Go back to step 2.
    // 7. Finish at last row, first column.
    private static void traverse() {
        int length = getLength();
        int total = matrix.length * matrix[0].length;
        System.out.println("Total = " + total);
        int row = 0;
        int col = matrix[row].length - 1;
        System.out.println("Start col = " + col);
        int count = 0;
        System.out.printf("%" + length + "d. First element [%" + length + "d][%" + length + "d] = %" + length + "d%n",
                          1,
                          row,
                          col,
                          matrix[row][col]);
        count++;
        while (count < total) {
            if (col - 1 >= 0) {
                col--;
                displayElement(row, col, length, count);
                count++;
            }
            else {
                if (row < matrix.length - 1) {
                    row++;
                    displayElement(row, col, length, count);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            while (row < matrix.length - 1  &&  col < matrix[row].length - 1) {
                row++;
                col++;
                displayElement(row, col, length, count);
                count++;
            }
            if (row < matrix.length - 1) {
                row++;
                displayElement(row, col, length, count);
                count++;
            }
            else {
                if (col - 1 >= 0) {
                    col--;
                    displayElement(row, col, length, count);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            while (row > 0  &&  col > 0) {
                row--;
                col--;
                displayElement(row, col, length, count);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Requires following two <tt>java</tt> command arguments (in listed order):
     * <ol>
     * <li>number of rows in matrix</li>
     * <li>number of columns in matrix</li>
     * </ol>
     * 
     * @param args - <tt>java</tt> command arguments.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 1) {
            int rows = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            int cols = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            initMatrix(rows, cols);
            traverse();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("ARGS: <# of rows in matrix> <# of columns in matrix>");
        }
    }
}
```

Tested on different dimensions including one row and several columns and one column and several rows. Here is the output for an 8x8 matrix.

```
rows = 8 , columns = 8

 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63

Total = 64
Start col = 7
 1. First element [ 0][ 7] =  7
 2. Next  element [ 0][ 6] =  6
 3. Next  element [ 1][ 7] = 15
 4. Next  element [ 2][ 7] = 23
 5. Next  element [ 1][ 6] = 14
 6. Next  element [ 0][ 5] =  5
 7. Next  element [ 0][ 4] =  4
 8. Next  element [ 1][ 5] = 13
 9. Next  element [ 2][ 6] = 22
10. Next  element [ 3][ 7] = 31
11. Next  element [ 4][ 7] = 39
12. Next  element [ 3][ 6] = 30
13. Next  element [ 2][ 5] = 21
14. Next  element [ 1][ 4] = 12
15. Next  element [ 0][ 3] =  3
16. Next  element [ 0][ 2] =  2
17. Next  element [ 1][ 3] = 11
18. Next  element [ 2][ 4] = 20
19. Next  element [ 3][ 5] = 29
20. Next  element [ 4][ 6] = 38
21. Next  element [ 5][ 7] = 47
22. Next  element [ 6][ 7] = 55
23. Next  element [ 5][ 6] = 46
24. Next  element [ 4][ 5] = 37
25. Next  element [ 3][ 4] = 28
26. Next  element [ 2][ 3] = 19
27. Next  element [ 1][ 2] = 10
28. Next  element [ 0][ 1] =  1
29. Next  element [ 0][ 0] =  0
30. Next  element [ 1][ 1] =  9
31. Next  element [ 2][ 2] = 18
32. Next  element [ 3][ 3] = 27
33. Next  element [ 4][ 4] = 36
34. Next  element [ 5][ 5] = 45
35. Next  element [ 6][ 6] = 54
36. Next  element [ 7][ 7] = 63
37. Next  element [ 7][ 6] = 62
38. Next  element [ 6][ 5] = 53
39. Next  element [ 5][ 4] = 44
40. Next  element [ 4][ 3] = 35
41. Next  element [ 3][ 2] = 26
42. Next  element [ 2][ 1] = 17
43. Next  element [ 1][ 0] =  8
44. Next  element [ 2][ 0] = 16
45. Next  element [ 3][ 1] = 25
46. Next  element [ 4][ 2] = 34
47. Next  element [ 5][ 3] = 43
48. Next  element [ 6][ 4] = 52
49. Next  element [ 7][ 5] = 61
50. Next  element [ 7][ 4] = 60
51. Next  element [ 6][ 3] = 51
52. Next  element [ 5][ 2] = 42
53. Next  element [ 4][ 1] = 33
54. Next  element [ 3][ 0] = 24
55. Next  element [ 4][ 0] = 32
56. Next  element [ 5][ 1] = 41
57. Next  element [ 6][ 2] = 50
58. Next  element [ 7][ 3] = 59
59. Next  element [ 7][ 2] = 58
60. Next  element [ 6][ 1] = 49
61. Next  element [ 5][ 0] = 40
62. Next  element [ 6][ 0] = 48
63. Next  element [ 7][ 1] = 57
64. Next  element [ 7][ 0] = 56
```